# Remembering that a user is logged in - where would I save information like this in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

Say a user logs in to a certain service in my app. How do I "remember" that the user did this, so it will no longer prompt him/her to do this?

For example, every time the app launches I want it to do something with the user account *if they are logged in* otherwise, don't do anything. The user logs in from an optional login window they can invoke. Once they login, I'd like to (conceptually at least) set a variable so I can be like `if (userIsLoggedIn) { ... }` and do things accordingly.

Is this NSUserDefaults? CoreData?

Comment: So, once they log in they never have to log in again? (As long as the app is active)?

Comment: I already have accomplished that through the service's SDK, it's more so that I'm looking for a way for the app to know that the user has already logged in, so don't present prompts, and only fetch using the service if they are logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily store it in NSUserDefaults.

```
// init
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// set the default value
[defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"loggedIn"];
// read value
NSString *loggedIn = [defaults objectForKey:@"loggedIn"]
```

**Update:**

Set with BOOL:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"loggedIn"];
```

read the value:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedIn"]) {
    // go to login screen
} else {
   // go to main screen
}
```

Comment: Why a string? Now you have to use `isEqualToString:` to find out what the setting is...

Comment: With NSUserDefaults you can also set an boolean, so you don't need to campare the string -> see my update

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults exposes your app to security risks if you are using login credentials.

I would recommend using **NSKeyedArchiver**.

This site has a fantastic simple explanation on how to implement it!

http://haoxiang.org/2011/11/ios-how-to-save-and-load-a-custom-object/

Apple API Doc just for future reference.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
```

Valid comments: you can also use `setBool:forKey` with the same result. Calling `synchronize` right after this assignment also does not hurt (although it is probably not critical).

Comment: Do I have to call synchronize after that?

Comment: You should: Synchronize: "Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And for this specific question I would use setBool

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` are automatically synchronized in the background. You only have to call `synchronize` if you need to ensure it persists right away, such as if you set something as the app is backgrounding.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out `NSUserDefaults` is useful if you are storing simple non private state.

I generally like to wrap this up with a category so that I can interact with user defaults easier and not have to worry about keys etc.

An example would look like this category

**NSUserDefaults+PASAuthorisation.h**

```
@interface NSUserDefaults (PASAuthorisation)

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=pas_isLoggedIn) BOOL pas_loggedIn;

@end
```

**NSUserDefaults+PASAuthorisation.m**

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+PASAuthorisation.h"

static NSString * const PASLogginInKey = @"PASLogginInKey";

@implementation NSUserDefaults (PASAuthorisation)

- (BOOL)pas_isLoggedIn;
{
  return [self boolForKey:PASLogginInKey];
}

- (void)setPas_loggedIn:(BOOL)pas_loggedIn;
{
  [self setBool:pas_loggedIn forKey:PASLogginInKey];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Core Data isn't really appropriate for small, unique pieces of data like this.

NSUserDefaults is the right place for small things like this, but if those small things are supposed to be secret -- like login details -- the Keychain is better.